# Deciding if a univariate quartic has a solution mod p

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have an equation in $x$ and I would like to determine if it has any solutions modulo a large prime $p$. Suppose $p$ is large enough that I can factor numbers up to $p$, but I cannot test all values up to $p$. (Actually, so far, I have been doing just that -- but I'd like to avoid this as it takes a long time. If you can avoid factoring, all the better.)

The particular equation I have is
$$
x^4-x^2\equiv4\pmod p
$$
but I would be interested in

1. Solutions to this particular problem, or more generally
2. Solutions to other quadratics$\pmod p$ in $x^2$, or more generally
3. Solutions to quartics$\pmod p$.

I'm familiar with quadratic reciprocity but not with cubic or biquadratic. (It's not clear to me if this can be transformed so they can be used; if so, demonstrating the transformation and giving a pointer to a good source on higher reciprocity would suffice as an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiaochu gives a nice general answer. For this particular problem, we can get our hands dirty to determine whether there's a solution.

Since $p>2$, you can apply the quadratic formula to see that $x^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \sqrt{17})$. Now, if you are working with a specific large prime $p$, you can use quadratic reciprocity to determine whether $\sqrt{17}$ exists, and then use quadratic reciprocity again to see whether a solution $x$ exists.

Comment: So this is really a solution for any $ax^4+bx^2\equiv c$, right? Very easy and useful.

Answer (score 3):

The product of the linear factors of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is given by

$$\gcd(x^p - x, f(x))$$

over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, which can be quickly computed for small $p$ by the Euclidean algorithm. For larger $p$, you can instead compute $x^p \bmod f(x)$ (thinking of $f(x)$ as an element of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$) by [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), being careful to reduce $\bmod f(x)$ at every step.

The problem of explicitly describing the set of primes $p$ for which some polynomial has a root $\bmod p$ requires higher reciprocity laws. When the Galois group of the polynomial is abelian, my understanding is that these can be deduced from general results in [class field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory). When the Galois group is nonabelian, my understanding is that higher reciprocity laws are open problems, closely related to the Langlands program. A very explicit example is the following: let

$$f(x) = x^3 - x - 1.$$

Then the splitting behavior of $f(x) \bmod p$ is determined by the $p^{th}$ coefficient of the  [modular form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form)

$$q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - q^n) (1 - q^{23n}).$$

See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers) for some details.

**Edit:** in this particular case, the Galois group is the Klein four group $C_2 \times C_2$, which is abelian. By the [Kronecker-Weber theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem), we then know that the splitting field of $f(x) = x^4 - x^2 = 4$ embeds into some cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, which implies that with finitely many exceptions the primes $p$ such that $f$ has a root $\bmod p$ are precisely the primes in some finite collection of arithmetic progressions with common difference $n$. To figure out exactly what these arithmetic progressions are one would need more specific information about the embedding into a cyclotomic field.